# Vertical scrolling when scrollbars are hidden

Tags: css, user-interface

I have a client who wants a similar functionality to the cargocollective theme [nonfeed](http://cargocollective.com/nonfeed), but we've noticed that this layout is basically impossible to navigate without a scroll wheel, multi-touch scrolling, or a mobile device. For instance, she has a netbook without a trackpad scroll feature, and it's impossible to navigate. I've also noticed that older folks grab the scrollbar with a mouse.

Obviously one option is to use `jQuery.scrollTop()` to scroll the individual divs with little arrows or something at the top/bottom of each div, but this does not seem like a great solution because it will be an extra button layer on top of everything. Another option is to just show the scrollbars, but that defeats the whole purpose.

How can this problem be solved: to retain the look of the blank rectangle, and allow scrolling without a wheel, with the least amount of extra garbage on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Okay what they have done was create a container div that will hide the scroll bar from sight. Then they use an inner div with the same width as the container except with a padding on the right that is scrollable only on the y.

HTML:

```
<div id='outer'>
   <div id='scrollArea'>
       Insert Info here.
   </div>
</div>

CSS:

#outer{
   width:500px;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
   background-color:#ccc;
   overflow:hidden;
}
#scrollArea{
   width:500px;
   height:100%;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   padding-right:50px;
}
html,body{
   margin:0 0 0 0;
   padding:0 0 0 0;
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/n6S5S/

Comment: This does not answer my question. I've successfully replicated their functionality; the issue is that their design mandates that the user scroll with a wheel, finger, multitouch pad, or however else. What about people who are on (for example) laptops without multitouch scroll capabilities?

Comment: Oh I see. Why not just have something like netflix has. When the user is on top of a carousel it will display 2 arrows (l & r) and in your case up and down. That will slide the element down.

Comment: Mentioned this in my post...wondering if there are any other solutions that don't involve adding more buttons covering things for 90% of the users who are comfortable with wheel/touch/finger scrolling.

Comment: I have been dealing with the same issue. I believe it is a Google Chrome bug that only occurs on UNIX systems, I have tested this and found that the issue must have something to do with the trackpad implementation. There is no scrollbar, but the trackpad still allows scrolling. I have also not been able to replicate it at all in Windows, but have not been able to suppress it in mac or linux.